# LEFT JOIN NOT APPEARING

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

Can someone please teach me what is wrong with this sql? When I run it the column for `LEFT JOIN` doesn't appear.

My table names are `asset_classification`, `country`, `currency`, `data`, `issuer`, `securities`.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT data.security_id, market_value, currency
FROM data
LEFT JOIN securities ON data.security_id=securities.security_id
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't appear?"  Do you mean the column is `NULL`?  That means the `LEFT JOIN` didn't match anything.  Are you sure there are rows in `securities` that match?

Comment: Is the column in the select clause on line 1?

Comment: yes there are rows that match, but the problem is the column itself dont want to appear. only this three colum from SELECT that appear in the result (security_id, market_value, currency). the left join didnt work.

Comment: you have to select the join columns too - SELECT data.security_id, market_value, currency, securities.column_name

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 1):

The columns for the join table are not in the `SELECT` statement

In addition to selecting `data.security_id, market_value, currency`, you also need to select any additional columns you want - the `LEFT JOIN` will link the tables but will not show the columns.

e.g. If the join table has the column `issuer`:

```
SELECT data.security_id, market_value, currency, issuer
FROM data
LEFT JOIN securities ON data.security_id=securities.security_id
```

To check the join is working and see all the columns try selecting all columns first:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
LEFT JOIN securities ON data.security_id=securities.security_id
```

Then rewrite the query to keep only the columns you need.

If both tables have a column called `issuer`, use:

```
SELECT data.security_id, market_value, currency, securities.issuer
FROM data
LEFT JOIN securities ON data.security_id=securities.security_id
```